# Dataframe in PySpark is not showing

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to display a dataframe but somehow it keeps telling me that not df is defined! How can this be? Here is the code:

```
for key, val in mapping_dict.items():
    target_table = key
    files, query, schema = val
    for file in files:
      try:
        df = sqlContext.read.format('csv').options(header='true', charset='UTF-16').schema(schema).load(file)
        #Convert column names to lowercases and replace spaces with underscores.
        df = df.toDF(*[(c.lower()).replace(' ','_') for c in df.columns])
        #Convert strings to date type.
        df = df.withColumn("date", to_date(df['date']))
        df.registerTempTable("dataTable")
        df = sqlContext.sql(query)
        )
      except Exception as e:
        print(e)
  return print("The loading is completed!")

df.head()
```

`The error is NameError: name 'df' is not defined`

Comment: The code you're showing is incomplete- what's that `return` doing there without a corresponding `def`?. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

this is scoping issue - you should learn best practices about code development or ask someone to help you structure the code.

The quick and dirty solution (in case this is a throwaway script), is to put `global df` on top of your function

```
def your_function(...):
    global df

    for key, val in mapping_dict.items():
        target_table = key
        files, query, schema = val
        for file in files:
    ...

df.head()
```